# Dialogflow - Fulfillment webhook with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a MySQL database inside my webhosting account (the database has a table with 20 columns and about 30000 rows).

I have to create a webhook to use with Dialogflow to retrieve and show database information (based on what the user enters into the chatbot) inside the chatbot.

Example:
If the user inserts "1" on chatbot prompt, then chatbot has to response with the content inside row 1 - column 3 of the database.

I don't have specific knowledge about Javascript: could you tell me where to find code to study about this case?

After, could I deploy the .js file inside my webhosting or I have to use external service as Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up webhook on in Dialogflow, that webhook basically a web server you can host anywhere and can be written in NodeJS, JAVA, or Dialogflow API supported languages.

[Here](https://medium.com/@abhinavkumar985/nodejs-webhook-for-dialogflow-fulfillment-a8e392b257b8) you can start with webhook can handle simple request and response, you can integrate it with database or any other service as well.